# Warning for questions with Clash of Clans tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-warning-request

Lots of [clash-of-clans](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clash-of-clans) questions are about "How to attack this base" even after the decision to make those question off-topic since these questions are usually from new users, who have no idea about this decision.

My suggestion is that whenever someone uses the Clash of Clans tag, a red pop-up will show up saying:

> Please make sure the question is not about how to attack a base, which is considered off-topic here

The pop-up would only be seen by people with less than 102 rep (to include people that got rep from assoc. bonus). Can this feature be implemented?

Comment: I think this is an interesting proposal... Sort of unusual compared to what I've seen on most SO sites though. I would think a simpler solution would be to be more clear in the off-topic flag reasons and even make sure to include this on the tour and help pages. New users are not exempt from knowing these pages after all, so as long as it's spelled out ahead of time we shouldn't need to be catching it later. But that's just my opinion! (and we all know many new users don't visit those pages...)

Comment: Note that all the other off-topic reasons don't have a warning on the relevant tag - even `game-identification`, which would probably benefit from it the most. If we're asking for it on Clash of Clans, we should ask for it on other tags aswell